# Insert a row into a dataframe based on values in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nested-loops

I want to insert a row into a dataframe based on values in another dataframe. I have attempted to reproduce my problem in a simple way.
I have two dataframes df1 and df2.

```
data = [['apple', 'apples'], ['orange', 'oranges'], ['banana', 'bananas'], ['kiwi', 'kiwis']]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['fruit', 'fruits'])

data_1 = [['apple', 'A'], ['banana', 'B'], ['cherry', 'C'], ['durian', 'D'], ['kiwi', 'K'], ['elderberry', 'E'], ['fig', 'F'], ['orangar', 'O']]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data_1, columns= ['fruit', 'label'])
```

The datframes look like this.

```
df1:
    fruit   fruits
0   apple   apples
1   orange  oranges
2   banana  bananas
3   kiwi    kiwi 


df2:
    fruit     label
0   apple       A
1   banana      B
2   cherry      C
3   durian      D
4   kiwi        K
5   elderberry  E
6   fig         F
7   orange      O
```

Now I want to combine the two datframes based on values in the 'fruit' column.
I have written a nested for loop to achieve my result.

```
line = pd.DataFrame(columns=['fruit', 'label'])
for i in range(len(df1)):
    for j in range(len(df2)):
        if df1.iloc[i]['fruit'] == df2.iloc[j]['fruit']:
            df2 = df2.append(pd.DataFrame({"fruit": df1.iloc[i]['fruits'], "label": df2.iloc[j]['label']}, index= [j+0.5]))
            df2 = df2.sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
```

The result looks like this:

```
df2:
fruit         label
0   apple       A
1   apples      A
2   banana      B
3   bananas     B
4   cherry      C
5   durian      D
6   kiwi        K
7   kiwis       K
8   elderberry  E
9   fig         F
10  orange      O
11  oranges     O
```

My original datasets have close to 30,000 values. This makes the nested for loop solution that I have used very slow. Is there a faster and more efficient way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let's do:

```
# get labels from df2
_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on='fruit')

# drop the old fruit column and rename fruits to fruit
_df = _df.drop('fruit', axis=1)
_df = _df.rename({'fruits': 'fruit'}, axis=1)

# concat the 2 dataframes together
df2 = pd.concat([df2, _df])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) with left join and then reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = (df2.merge(df1, on='fruit', how='left')
         .set_index('label')
         .stack()
         .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
         .reset_index(name='fruit')[['fruit','label']])
print (df)
         fruit label
0        apple     A
1       apples     A
2       banana     B
3      bananas     B
4       cherry     C
5       durian     D
6         kiwi     K
7        kiwis     K
8   elderberry     E
9          fig     F
10     orangar     O
```